# Standard deviation

Tags: statistics

You are estimating the cost of a personnel shelter and you have collected cost data on $10$ shelters. The mean cost was $\$16,693$. The median cost is $\$17,402$. There is a range in the cost of $\$10,095$. The standard deviation is $\$3,270$. If you use the average cost of the shelters as your estimate, then, on average:

You could expect to be off by $20.42\%$.

You could expect to be off by $\$10,095$.

You could expect to be off by $\$340.90$.

You could expect to be off by $19.59\%$.

Comment: Not clear to me what your question is.  Are we meant to prove each of those statements?  Are some true and others false?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: What does "you could expect" mean?  I am pessimistic...I often expect the worst.  Should that play a role in my computation?

Comment: It seems to me a multiple choice question...

Answer (score 0):

3,270/16,693=19.59%
I am in this course, this is a question from Defense Acquisition University (Government)